# Pandas Merge More Efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple tables that need to be merged in my code, but all have a lot of additional columns of 'fluff' attached to them. My current process for merging tables is the following:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=[key])
df = pd.drop([[insert not-needed columns], axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={'column_x': 'column'})
```

I've also seen people isolate columns in a new lookup table first:

```
ref = df2['column1','key']
df = pd.merge(df, ref, on=[key])
```

Is there a faster way to do something similar to a VLOOKUP (but include more than one column) in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can filter it before `merge` which should be faster then filter after `merge`

```
ref = df2[['col1','col2',...., 'coln','key']]
df = pd.merge(df, ref, on=[key])
```

Comment: If I am doing this more than once, would it save time to overwrite the ref dataframe with the new columns OR just do ref2 3 4 etc